# Difference between .WithMany() and .WithOptional()?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, fluent-interface

Below are two similar fluent API configurations:

**WithMany()**

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Country>()
            .HasRequired(cou => cou.Currency)
            .WithMany()
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

**WithOptional()**

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Country>()
            .HasRequired(cou => cou.Currency)
            .WithOptional()
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

What I am trying to express here is: Every `Country` requires a concrete `Currency`, but a `Currency` can be assigned to zero, one or many Countries.

Which of the above statements would I have to use? Or in other words: What exactly is the difference between `.WithMany()` and `.WithOptional()` operators?

Comment: Did you mean the title and description to refer to .WithMany() and .WithOptional() instead of .HasMany() and .HasOptional()? I've submitted an edit.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If your model would look like this:

```
public class Country
{
    public int CountryId { get; set; }
    public Currency Currency { get; set; }
}

public class Currency
{
    public int CurrencyId { get; set; }
}
```

then ...

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Country>()
            .HasRequired(cou => cou.Currency)
            .WithOptional()
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

... creates a foreign key relationship in the database where `CountryId` in the `Countries` table is primary key and foreign key to the `CurrencyId` of the `Currencies` table at the same time, so the `Countries` table has **only one single column** `CountryId`. A `Currencies` record can live without a related `Countries` record. But if a `Currencies` record has a related `Countries` record then not more than one because the foreign key is `CountryId` which is the primary key at the same time and can therefore only be in one record. So the relationship `Currencies -> Countries` is `1-to-0...1`.

The other example ...

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Country>()
            .HasRequired(cou => cou.Currency)
            .WithMany()
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

... creates **a second column** `CurrencyId` in the `Countries` table of the database which is non-nullable and is a foreign key to the `CurrencyId` of the `Currencies` table. So here it is possible that a `Currencies` record has no related `Countries` record or one or more than one because the foreign key is now another column, not identical with the primary key. Therefore more than one row in the `Countries` table may have the same foreign key. The relationship `Currencies -> Countries` here is `1-to-0...n`.

**Edit**

If you take the following code for the two differently configured models ...

```
Country country1 = new Country();
Country country2 = new Country();
Currency currency = new Currency();

country1.Currency = currency;
country2.Currency = currency;

context.Countries.Add(country1);
context.Countries.Add(country2);

context.SaveChanges();
```

... then the second case (.WithMany) works: We get two new Countries and one Currency in the database.

However a bit strange is that in the second case (.HasOptional) only the first Country is stored, the second is simply ignored. Actually I had expected to get an exception. I am not sure if that has to be considered as a bug.

**Edit2**

Changing the order in the example above to ...

```
context.Countries.Add(country1);
context.Countries.Add(country2);

country1.Currency = currency;
country2.Currency = currency;
```

... throws the expected exception in the ".HasOptional" case.

Comment: Ah, got it. So, .HasOptional() is for 1 <-> 0|1 and .HasMany() is for 1 <-> 0|n relationships. Great. This is what I wanted to know. Thanks so much!!!

Comment: @Ingmar: Take a look at my Edit, may be worth to know. I just discovered that, perhaps there is a bug with 1 <-> 0|1 relationship.