# Entity Framework root navigation property null but descendent navigation property populated

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

A navigation property on a root model always returns null while a secondary relationship on the same model that is defined similarly loads correctly. I'm trying to find out why.

Using EF6 Code First, eager loading, I have models/navigation properties structured like this:

- ProjectUser

  - Project (always null)
  - User (loads fine)
  - Groups (loads fine)

    - Clients

      - Project (populated correctly - should always be same as ProjectUser.Project)

My *ProjectUser.Project* is always null but interestingly the *ProjectUser.Groups.Clients.Project* is populated correctly. My project is mapped like so:

```
HasRequired(pu => pu.Project)
    .WithOptional()
    .Map(m => m.MapKey("ProjectId"));
```

To further make things confusing I am actually able to get the Project to load if in the above mapping I change `WithOptional()` to be `WithMany()`. However this doesn't make sense to me... So my question is:

Why is ProjectUser.Project not loading when using `WithOptional`?

Comment: Can't reproduce. Make sure the model and database are in sync. Also the data is correct (there are no duplicate `ProjectId` in `ProjectUser` table since the relationship you set up is `one-to-one`)

Answer (score 0):

WithMany means that your entity might have many of the navigation property as it's called 1-to-many.

WithOptional means that your entity might have one of the navigation property. A one-to-one relationship.

Take a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5421707/ef-4-1-difference-between-withmany-and-withoptional).