# HasRequired and WithOptional not generating one-to-one relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio-2017, entity-framework-6, fluent

I have, two very simple objects:

```
public class GenericObject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public User UserWhoGeneratedThisObject { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }  
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
}
```

I am overriding the OnModelCreating function to declare the objects' relationships:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<GenericObject>().HasRequired(u => u.UserWhoGeneratedThisObject)
                                   .WithOptional();
    }
```

Then, in my application, I do the following:

```
using (var ctx = new TestContext())
{
    GenericObject myObject = new GenericObject();
    myObject.description = "testobjectdescription";
    User usr = new User() { Name = "Test"};
    ctx.Users.Add(usr);
    //myObject.UserWhoGeneratedThisObject = usr;
    ctx.GenericObjects.Add(myObject);
    ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

Shouldn't I be hitting an exception when I am adding the myObject to the database, since I haven't assigned it a User object? (The commented out line) I expected to see an exception in this case, but the code works OK. To make matters worse, if I add the following two lines after ctx.SaveChanges():

```
var u = ctx.GenericObjects.Find(1);
System.Console.WriteLine(u.ToString());
```

I see that the variable u which is a GenericObjects actually points to the user that I created in the database, even though I didn't assign the user to the GenericObject.

Comment: You did not specify whether error is throwing or not? Or data is populating to the database or not? Please ask question with clear information about the state.

Comment: Okay! I have checked that its inserting data to database making relation  between each other.

Comment: Yes, sorry, edited it to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should read: [Difference between .WithMany() and .WithOptional()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5421707/difference-between-withmany-and-withoptional)

the code:

```
using (var ctx = new Tests6Context()) {
    GenericObject myObject = new GenericObject();
    myObject.description = "testobjectdescription";
    User usr = new User() { Name = "Test" };
    ctx.Users.Add(usr);
    //myObject.UserWhoGeneratedThisObject = usr;
    ctx.GenericObjects.Add(myObject);


    myObject = new GenericObject();
    myObject.description = "testobjectdescription 2";
    usr = new User() { Name = "Test 2" };
    ctx.Users.Add(usr);
    //myObject.UserWhoGeneratedThisObject = usr;
    ctx.GenericObjects.Add(myObject);

    ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

throws:

> System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException: Unable to determine the principal end of the 'ef6tests.GenericObject_UserWhoGeneratedThisObject' relationship. Multiple added entities may have the same primary key.

In simple case one new User and one new GenericObject EF infers the only relation possible between two entities in the same state. In other cases he throws.

Comment: Ah! So simple, yet so strange. I also just realized (and edited the question accordingly), if I add one GenericObject, and then query it, it points to the only user defined in the Users table, even though I didn't assign to it!

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR**

This behavior is not specific for `one-to-one` relationship, `one-to-many` behaves exactly the same way.

If you want to make EF throw an exception with your current code then map separate foreign key for `GenericObject`

```
modelBuilder
    .Entity<GenericObject>()
    .HasRequired(u => u.UserWhoGeneratedThisObject)
    .WithOptional()
    .Map(config =>
    {
        config.MapKey("UserId");
    });
```

**Actual answer**

Actually `one-to-many` relationship suffers from exactly the same problem. Let's do some tests.

**One-to-one**

```
public class GenericObject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public UserObject UserWhoGeneratedThisObject { get; set; }
}

public class UserObject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Configuration

```
modelBuilder
    .Entity<GenericObject>()
    .HasRequired(u => u.UserWhoGeneratedThisObject)
    .WithOptional();
```

In this case `GenericObject.Id` is a primary key and a foreign key references `UserObject` entity at the same time.

**Test 1. Create only GenericObject**

```
var context = new AppContext();

GenericObject myObject = new GenericObject
{
    Description = "some description"
};

context.GenericObjects.Add(myObject);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Executed query

```
INSERT [dbo].[GenericObjects]([Id], [Description])
VALUES (@0, @1)

-- @0: '0' (Type = Int32)

-- @1: 'some description' (Type = String, Size = -1)
```

Exception

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.GenericObjects_dbo.UserObjects_Id". The conflict occurred in database "TestProject", table "dbo.UserObjects", column 'Id'.
>   The statement has been terminated.

Since `GenericObject` is the only entity EF executes `insert` query and it fails because there is no `UserObject` with `Id` equals `0` in database.

**Test 2. Create 1 UserObject and a GenericObject**

```
var context = new AppContext();

GenericObject myObject = new GenericObject
{
    Description = "some description"
};

UserObject user = new UserObject
{
    Name = "user"
};

context.UserObjects.Add(user);
context.GenericObjects.Add(myObject);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Executed queries

```
INSERT [dbo].[UserObjects]([Name])
VALUES (@0)
SELECT [Id]
FROM [dbo].[UserObjects]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND [Id] = scope_identity()

-- @0: 'user' (Type = String, Size = -1)

INSERT [dbo].[GenericObjects]([Id], [Description])
VALUES (@0, @1)

-- @0: '10' (Type = Int32)

-- @1: 'some description' (Type = String, Size = -1)
```

Now context contains `UserObject` (Id = 0) and `GenericObject` (Id = 0). EF considers that `GenericObject` references to the `UserObject` because its foreign key equals 0 as well as `UserObject` primary key equals 0. So at first EF inserts `UserObject` as a principal and because it consider `GenericObject` dependent on that user it takes returned `UserObject.Id` and performs second insert with it and eveything is fine.

**Test 3. Create 2 UserObject and a GenericObject**

```
var context = new AppContext();

GenericObject myObject = new GenericObject
{
    Description = "some description"
};

UserObject user = new UserObject
{
    Name = "user"
};
UserObject user2 = new UserObject
{
    Name = "user"
};

context.UserObjects.Add(user);
context.UserObjects.Add(user2);
context.GenericObjects.Add(myObject);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Exception

> 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll
>
> Additional information: Unable to determine the principal end of the 'TestConsole.Data.GenericObject_UserWhoGeneratedThisObject' relationship. Multiple added entities may have the same primary key.

EF sees that there are 2 `UserObject` in context with `Id` equals `0` and `GenericObject.Id` equals 0 as well, so the framework just unable to definitely connect entities because there are multiple possible options.

**One-to-many**

```
public class GenericObject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public int UserId { get; set; } //this property is essential to illistrate the problem

    public UserObject UserWhoGeneratedThisObject { get; set; }
}

public class UserObject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Configuration

```
modelBuilder
    .Entity<GenericObject>()
    .HasRequired(o => o.UserWhoGeneratedThisObject)
    .WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey(o => o.UserId);
```

In this case `GenericObject` has separate `UserId` as a foreign key referencing `UserObject` entity.

**Test 1. Create only GenericObject**

Same code as in `one-to-one`. It executes the same query and yields the same exception. Reason is the same.

**Test 2. Create 1 UserObject and a GenericObject**

Same code as in `one-to-one`.

Executed queries

```
INSERT [dbo].[UserObjects]([Name])
VALUES (@0)
SELECT [Id]
FROM [dbo].[UserObjects]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND [Id] = scope_identity()

-- @0: 'user' (Type = String, Size = -1)

-- Executing at 14.03.2019 18:52:35 +02:00

INSERT [dbo].[GenericObjects]([Description], [UserId])
VALUES (@0, @1)
SELECT [Id]
FROM [dbo].[GenericObjects]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND [Id] = scope_identity()

-- @0: 'some description' (Type = String, Size = -1)

-- @1: '3' (Type = Int32)
```

Executed queries are pretty similar to `one-to-one` test 2. The only difference is that now `GenericObject` has separate `UserId` foreign key. Reasoning is pretty the same. Context contains `UserObject` entity with `Id` equal `0` and `GenericObject` with `UserId` equals now so EF considers them connected and performs insert of `UserObject` then it takes `UserObject.Id` and performs second insert with it.

**Test 3. Create 2 UserObject and a GenericObject**

Same code as in `one-to-one`. It executes the same query and yields the same exception. Reason is the same.

As you can see from these tests the problem is not specific to `one-to-one` relationship.

But what if we don't add `UserId` to `GenericObject`? In this case EF will generate `UserWhoGeneratedThisObject_Id` foreign key for us and now there is foreign key in database but no property mapped to it. In this case every single test will immediately throw the following exception

> Entities in 'AppContext.GenericObjects' participate in the 'GenericObject_UserWhoGeneratedThisObject' relationship. 0 related 'GenericObject_UserWhoGeneratedThisObject_Target' were found. 1 'GenericObject_UserWhoGeneratedThisObject_Target' is expected.

Why this happens? Now EF unable to determine whether `GenericObject` and `UserObject` are connected because there is no foreign key property on `GenericObject`. In this case EF can rely only on navigation property `UserWhoGeneratedThisObject` which is `null` and therefore an exception is raised.

It means if you can achieve this situation for `one-to-one` when there is a foreign key in database but no property is mapped to it EF will throw the same exception for the code in your question. It's easy to accomplish by updating configuration

```
modelBuilder
    .Entity<GenericObject>()
    .HasRequired(u => u.UserWhoGeneratedThisObject)
    .WithOptional()
    .Map(config =>
    {
        config.MapKey("UserId");
    });
```

The `Map` method tells EF to create separate `UserId` foreign key in `GenericObject`. With this change the code in your question will throw an exception

```
using (var ctx = new TestContext())
{
    GenericObject myObject = new GenericObject();
    myObject.description = "testobjectdescription";
    User usr = new User() { Name = "Test"};
    ctx.Users.Add(usr);
    //myObject.UserWhoGeneratedThisObject = usr;
    ctx.GenericObjects.Add(myObject);
    ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

> Entities in 'AppContext.GenericObjects' participate in the 'GenericObject_UserWhoGeneratedThisObject' relationship. 0 related 'GenericObject_UserWhoGeneratedThisObject_Target' were found. 1 'GenericObject_UserWhoGeneratedThisObject_Target' is expected.

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed explanation

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up both navigation properties:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
   modelBuilder.Entity<GenericObject>()
      .HasRequired(genericObject => genericObject.UserWhoGeneratedThisObject)
      .WithOptional(user => user.GenericObject);
}
```

Comment: But, my User object does not have a GenericObject member. I simply have no interest or intention of querying a User and finding out which GenericObject(s) it is being pointed from.

Comment: You have no chance to declare 1:1-0 relationship without having navigation properties in both classes.

Comment: Really? So let me ask you this. Suppose I am designing a database. This database will have dozens of tables (Part Number, BoM, Address, Stock, Location, Customer, Supplier, etc.). I want to keep track, which User generated each of the rows in these tables. Should be User object then have a navigation property for the dozens of classes that I define? That seems very counter-intuitive.

Comment: This is 1:N relationship you are talking about, not 1:1-0, unless you want to allow your users to create/edit at most 1 entity per entity type ;-)

Comment: OK I see your point. I now realize that my question is not very clear. I shouldn't have said "one-to-one relationship" in the title. I was just wondering why I am not hitting an exception, and @tschmit007 below seems to have found out the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

> Shouldn't I be hitting an exception when I am adding the myObject to the database, since I haven't assigned it a User object? (The commented out line)

I think no because of one-to-one relation was not created in data base with your "OnModelCreating" function implementation.
GenericObjectId property which will be marked as foreign key by "[ForeignKey]" attribute should be created to create one-to-one relation in "User" class. "GenericObject" property should be added to "User" class and marked with virtual modifier. Now your implementation of "OnModelCreating" will configure relationships between these classes.
There are examples of models:

```
public class User
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Lastname { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("GenericObject")]
        public int GenericObjectId { get; set; }

        public virtual GenericObject GenericObject { get; set; }
    }

public class GenericObject
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }        

        public virtual User UserWhoGeneratedThisObject { get; set; }
    }
```

[After relations will be mapped, searched exception will be appeared:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbqvS.png)

Generic object should be created at first and created object id should be added to new user to avoid this exception(This is in case if you put foreign key to user).

Hopefully I answered for your question clearly.